# Geolocation example from Phonegap gives alerts with errors on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, geolocation

I was trying the Geolocation example from the below link.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

I copied the entire content from the first 'Full Example' and saved that file as an HTML. When I opened it in Chrome (desktop) and Android phone inbuilt browser(default), I got the following three alerts on both chrome and android phone.

1. gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","XXXXXXXXXX"]
2. gap:["NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","XXXXXXXXXX"]
3. gap:["App","show","XXXXXXXXXX"]

I clicked 'Cancel' first time and even tried 'Ok' but, nothing happens. If I click 'OK' on all three alerts on my Android Phone, the page goes all white.

So I googled it and found couple of answers on Stack Overflow suggesting:

- To remove the Cordova JS file for the desktop browser
- Add android specific JS from the Cordova.

So I tried both but none of them worked. Latest, I tried the following solution.

I downloaded the `Cordova package (3.0.0),` there was a `cordova-android.zip` which had the cordova.js file at the following path.

```
/cordova-android/framework/assets/www/cordova.js
```

So, now my script element looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/cordova-android/framework/assets/www/cordova.js">
```

After modified the `<script>` element as above, I don't get alerts in Chrome, but I still get following NEW alerts on my Android phone.

1. gap:["PluginManager","startup","Plugin ManagerXXXXXXXXXX"]
2. gap:["App","show","XXXXXXXXXX"]
3. Code: 1, message: User denied Geolocation.

So, now I have following questions:

1. How do I solve this problem (to run the HTML page without alert on all devices/browser)?
2. Any idea on why did my alerts change after changing the cordova.js file?

Regards,
Rumit

Comment: Are you saying you only have an HTML file and the cordova.js file, and you're trying to run this in Chrome on a PC and in the browser on an Android phone?

Comment: Yes, its just an HTML and cordova.js. Running on Chrome browser and Android phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using cordova.js as if it's a JS library like jQuery, but Phonegap (Cordova) is a hybrid framework not a mobile browser framework ([see here for clarification](http://www.asyncdev.net/2012/10/phonegap-a-misunderstood-hybrid-framework/)). It's not intended to be used as a standalone JS library in a webpage, but in conjunction with a native Phonegap library in order to build a native application. If you created your page as a Phonegap app and built it for Android, you would be able to (and need to) allow the app permission to use geolocation.

Phonegap apps are implemented via a native WebView and in the case of the Geolocation API, Phonegap will use only use its own implementation if the device doesn't already have a native W3C implementation (which Android does).

So the point is: either create a proper Phonegap app for Android by following the [platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) or simply don't use the Phonegap JS at all since you can call the Android browser's geolocation API (navigator.geolocation) directly from Javascript in your webpage - you don't need Phonegap's JS file to allow you to do this (have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367994/javascript-geolocation-on-android-doesnt-work)).