# Navigator.getLocation.getCurrentPosition is not working on Android mobile

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have js code which gets which gets users lat long but the problem is when I call the js function its not working on Android browser using Chrome. My android mobile location is turned On and Allowed to this web page too.
i tried to used `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{ enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout : 5000,maxAge:1000});` and it says `The request to get user location timed out,` TimeOut Error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367994/javascript-geolocation-on-android-doesnt-work

Comment: this also working only on desktop, not working on android device